# What is the PyMC3 equivalent of the 'pymc.rnormal' function?

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3

Is there a PyMC3 equivalent to the `pymc.rnormal` function, or has it been dropped in favor of `numpy.random.normal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it... a bit silly of me. `pymc3.Normal(mu,sd).random()`, which basically just calls `scipy.stats.norm`